# react native recognize device rotation

Tags: ios, react-native

I follow [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) and want to recognize different rotation.

so I do `navigator.push()` and execute `lockToLANDSCAPE` in `componentDidMount` method and I get `LANDSCAPE` orientation.

then I want to `navigator.pop()` and expect back to `PORTRAIT` orientation, so I call `lockToPortrait` after `pop`, it works.

.. but I find that device orientation can't change to `PORTRAIT` if I already put my device in `PORTRAIT` orientation **(`lockToLANDSCAPE` now)** when I prepare to `pop`.

how should I fix it?

thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, this seems to me to be more of a package problem than something you should solve manually. Maybe you should open an issue for it on the react-native-orientation page.

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen thanks for your suggestion, I opened an issue :)